# Django-debug-toolbar not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using django 4.0.3 and django-debug-toolbar 3.2.4. For some reason, the toolbar is not showing on my server.I tried many ways but none of them worked for me. I will be very grateful for any help

> **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# debug_toolbar moved here.
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE += [
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ]
    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'debug_toolbar',
    ]
    INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', ]

    # this is the main reason for not showing up the toolbar
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

> **urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG=True` set on your server? It defaults to `False`.

Comment: Yes, I am have DEBUG=TRUE on my server

Comment: I suspect the issue is that your IP address is not listed in the `INTERNAL_IPS` setting - it's currently set to only localhost, which will not work if the server is on a different machine to yours. https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configure-internal-ips

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok to me. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

In case of *Google Chrome*, goto **Settings>More tools>Clear browsing data...** or **Ctrl+Shift+Del**

Answer (score -1):

You need to add "debug_toolbar" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

[Docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-the-app)